# R BB package - no way to pass parameters to objective function?

Tags: r, equation-solving, nonlinear-optimization

I am eager to use the R package BB to solve a system of non-linear equations, but the syntax does not seem to allow for parameters to be passed to the system of equations. Very strange since this would severely limit what appears to be an otherwise very appealing and powerful alternative to nleqslv().

To be clear: "Normally", you expect a solver to have a space for passing parameters to the underlying objective function. For eg. in nleqslv:

```
out <- nleqslv(in_x, obj_fn, jac = NULL, other_pars1, other_pars2, method = "Broyden")
```

Where "in_x" is the vector of initial guesses at a solution, and the "other_pars1, other_pars2" are additional fixed parameters (can be scalars, vectors, matrices, whatever) required by "obj_fn".

In BBsolve, on the other hand, you just have

```
out <- BBsolve(in_x, obj_fn)
```

With no space to put in all the "other_pars1, other_pars2" required by obj_fn.

Comment: When I read the `BBsolve` documentation I see that that `BBsolve` certainly does accept additional arguments via the `...` construct. So I don't quite understand what you mean or what you have been doing exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that "attaches" additional parameters to your objective function. The key concept here is that the return value is itself a function:

```
gen_obj_fn <- function( obj_fn, other_pars1, other_pars2 )
{
  function(x) { obj_fn( x, other_pars1, other_pars2 ) }
}
```

The output of `gen_obj_fn` can now be passed directly to `BBsolve`:

```
## Previous call using nleqslv():
out <- nleqslv( in_x, myFun, jac = NULL, myParam1, myParam2, ... )

## Equivalent call using BBsolve():
myObjF <- gen_obj_fn( myFun, myParam1, myParam2 )
is.function( myObjF )  ## TRUE
out <- BBsolve( in_x, myObjF )
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: BBsolve is not stopping when it finds a solution. That is to say, for 4 equations it finds a solution which outputs c(0.001, 0.002, -0.001, 0.001)--close enough to the roots for me!--But then it keeps going until maxit is reached, whereupon it reports failure. I have changed the tol to 1e-02, but this doesn't help, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you are using `BBsolve`. As I said in my comment `BBsolve` certainly does accept additional function arguments.
But you must name those arguments.

See this example for how to do what you seem to want:

```
library(nleqslv)

f <- function(x,p1=3,p2=2) {
  y <- numeric(2)
  y[1] <- 10*x[1]+3*x[2]^2 - p1
  y[2] <- x[1]^2 -exp(x[2]) -p2
  y
}

xstart <- c(1,1)
nleqslv(xstart, f)

library(BB)
BBsolve(xstart,f)
```

Try slightly different values for `p1` and `p2`:

```
nleqslv(xstart,f,p1=2.7,p2=2.1)
BBsolve(xstart,f,p1=2.7,p2=2.1)
```

Both functions find the same solution.

Comment: Yes, but this way requires an inline function. My function is too big and messy for that.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If you can do it the way you show with `nleqslv` then you can do it the same way in `BBsolve`.